# YOLOv5 Evolution Results Not Reproducible wandb

Tags: python, yolov5, wandb

I am running YOLOv5 in a sagemaker notebook.
The 10 epoch runs are using the following notebook script making use of the --evolve flag for hyperparameters.

```
!export WANDB_RUN_GROUP="evolution" && python ./deepsea-yolov5/yolov5/train.py
--img=640
--data=./deepsea-yolov5/opt/ml/custom_config.yaml
--batch=2
--weights=yolov5s.pt
--cfg=./deepsea-yolov5/yolov5/models/yolov5s.yaml
--project="902005-vaa"
--cache
--epochs=10
--evolve=30
```

Evolution runs only output one point on the graph at the end of 10 epochs and the outputted hyperparameters do not show reproducible results when running in a 50 epoch run. The blue 50 epoch line showcases using the optimal hyperparameters which should intersect with the highest 10 epoch run, but it doesn't reach anywhere close.
[image]

After finding the optimal hyperparameters I ran a 50 epoch run using those parameters using the following command.

```
!export WANDB_RUN_GROUP="hyperparam" && python ./deepsea-yolov5/yolov5/train.py
--img=640
--data=./deepsea-yolov5/opt/ml/custom_config.yaml
--batch=2
--weights=yolov5s.pt
--cfg=./deepsea-yolov5/yolov5/models/yolov5s.yaml
--hyp=./deepsea-yolov5/opt/ml/input/data/hyp.scratch-low.yaml
--project="902005-vaa"
--cache
--epochs=50
```

However as shown in the picture above, the runs do not intersect with the best-performing hyperparameter run.